# How can I associate a consistent polygon area with a set of attributes using a topology?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, topology

Consider the following topology.

```
SELECT CreateTopology('topotestschema', 0, 0.01);
CREATE TABLE topotest (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, data TEXT);
SELECT AddTopoGeometryColumn('topotestschema', 'public', 'topotest', 'topogeom', 'polygon');
INSERT INTO topotest (data, topogeom) VALUES ('outer', toTopoGeom('POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))'::geometry, 'topotestschema', 1, 0.01));
```

When we look at what's in the topology:

```
SELECT *, ST_AsText(topogeom::geometry) FROM topotest;
```

we get

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ data  ║ topogeom  ║                 st_astext                 ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ outer ║ (3,1,1,3) ║ MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))) ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

But this gets changed around when I add more shapes:

```
INSERT INTO topotest (data, topogeom)
VALUES
('right', toTopoGeom('POLYGON((9 1,11 1,11 9,9 9,9 1))'::geometry, 'topotestschema', 1, 0.01))
,('inner', toTopoGeom('POLYGON((3 3,3 7,7 7,7 3,3 3))'::geometry, 'topotestschema', 1, 0.01))
;
```

Now the layer is:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ data  ║ topogeom  ║                      st_astext                       ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ outer ║ (3,1,1,3) ║ MULTIPOLYGON(((10 9,10 1,10 0,0 0,0 10,10 10,10 9))) ║
║  2 ║ right ║ (3,1,2,3) ║ MULTIPOLYGON(((10 9,11 9,11 1,10 1,9 1,9 9,10 9)))   ║
║  3 ║ inner ║ (3,1,3,3) ║ MULTIPOLYGON(((3 3,3 7,7 7,7 3,3 3)))                ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

How can I keep it from modifying the polygon associated with existing rows when I add new ones?

Please feel free to say something if it seems like I'm on entirely the wrong track here. I'm basically experimenting with a topology and trying to figure out if it's useful for what I'm doing.